# IntelliJ sbt project automatically creates lib folder

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Has anyone an idea why my Intellij sbt project creates a lib folder containing jars when opened?
When refreshing the sbt project manually the folder is not created.

I don't understand why this is happening automatically, because the library management documentation says this folder is for manually editing unmanaged dependencies: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably have checked the box 'Create directories for empty content roots automatically' in the initial SBT project import / creation dialog. Re-import project without it and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do remember unchecking this setting, though I did not re-import the whole project. Is re-importing strictly necessary for these settings to apply? That'd be quite strange : ) Anyways, unchecking did not solve the problem, only deleting the files created by sbt with "sbt clean" worked. (And I know it is not really a fix to this problem, just a dirty workaround)

Answer (score -1):

I just ran "sbt clean" from the command line and the problem disappeared.